# Multiple JSON root elements - Twitter API stream

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I saw this question asked before but the answers did not help me so I will give it a go here:

I am streaming live tweets from the Twitter API using Twython. These tweets are appended to a json file using:

```
with open('fetched_tweets.json','a') as tf:
               y = json.dump(data,tf)
```

**My problem:**

Here is an example of a JSON response from twitter API:

```
{
  "text": "RT @PostGradProblem: In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during ...", 
  "truncated": true, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
  "favorited": false, 
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", 
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
  "id_str": "54691802283900928", 
  "entities": {
        "user_mentions": [
              {
                    "indices": [
                          3, 
                          19
                    ], 
                    "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
                    "id_str": "271572434", 
                    "name": "PostGradProblems", 
                    "id": 271572434
              }
        ], 
        "urls": [ ], 
        "hashtags": [ ]
  }, 
  "contributors": null, 
  "retweeted": false, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
  "place": null, 
  "retweet_count": 4, 
  "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 23:48:36 +0000 2011", 
  "retweeted_status": {
        "text": "In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during company time. #PGP", 
        "truncated": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite</a>", 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "id_str": "54640519019642881", 
        "entities": {
              "user_mentions": [ ], 
              "urls": [ ], 
              "hashtags": [
                    {
                          "text": "PGP", 
                          "indices": [
                                130, 
                                134
                          ]
                    }
              ]
        }, 
        "contributors": null, 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "place": null, 
        "retweet_count": 4, 
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 20:24:49 +0000 2011", 
        "user": {
              "notifications": null, 
              "profile_use_background_image": true, 
              "statuses_count": 31, 
              "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
              "followers_count": 3066, 
              "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
              "listed_count": 6, 
              "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1301071706/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
              "description": "", 
              "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
              "default_profile": true, 
              "verified": false, 
              "time_zone": null, 
              "profile_text_color": "333333", 
              "is_translator": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
              "location": "", 
              "id_str": "271572434", 
              "default_profile_image": false, 
              "profile_background_tile": false, 
              "lang": "en", 
              "friends_count": 21, 
              "protected": false, 
              "favourites_count": 0, 
              "created_at": "Thu Mar 24 19:45:44 +0000 2011", 
              "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
              "name": "PostGradProblems", 
              "show_all_inline_media": false, 
              "follow_request_sent": null, 
              "geo_enabled": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
              "url": null, 
              "id": 271572434, 
              "contributors_enabled": false, 
              "following": null, 
              "utc_offset": null
        }, 
        "id": 54640519019642880, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "geo": null
  }, 
  "user": {
        "notifications": null, 
        "profile_use_background_image": true, 
        "statuses_count": 351, 
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
        "followers_count": 48, 
        "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/455128973/gCsVUnofNqqyd6tdOGevROvko1_500_normal.jpg", 
        "listed_count": 0, 
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1300479984/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "description": "watcha doin in my waters?", 
        "screen_name": "OldGREG85", 
        "default_profile": true, 
        "verified": false, 
        "time_zone": "Hawaii", 
        "profile_text_color": "333333", 
        "is_translator": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
        "location": "Texas", 
        "id_str": "80177619", 
        "default_profile_image": false, 
        "profile_background_tile": false, 
        "lang": "en", 
        "friends_count": 81, 
        "protected": false, 
        "favourites_count": 0, 
        "created_at": "Tue Oct 06 01:13:17 +0000 2009", 
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
        "name": "GG", 
        "show_all_inline_media": false, 
        "follow_request_sent": null, 
        "geo_enabled": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
        "url": null, 
        "id": 80177619, 
        "contributors_enabled": false, 
        "following": null, 
        "utc_offset": -36000
  }, 
  "id": 54691802283900930, 
  "coordinates": null, 
  "geo": null
} {
  "text": "RT @PostGradProblem: In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during ...", 
  "truncated": true, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
  "favorited": false, 
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", 
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
  "id_str": "54691802283900928", 
  "entities": {
        "user_mentions": [
              {
                    "indices": [
                          3, 
                          19
                    ], 
                    "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
                    "id_str": "271572434", 
                    "name": "PostGradProblems", 
                    "id": 271572434
              }
        ], 
        "urls": [ ], 
        "hashtags": [ ]
  }, 
  "contributors": null, 
  "retweeted": false, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
  "place": null, 
  "retweet_count": 4, 
  "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 23:48:36 +0000 2011", 
  "retweeted_status": {
        "text": "In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during company time. #PGP", 
        "truncated": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite</a>", 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "id_str": "54640519019642881", 
        "entities": {
              "user_mentions": [ ], 
              "urls": [ ], 
              "hashtags": [
                    {
                          "text": "PGP", 
                          "indices": [
                                130, 
                                134
                          ]
                    }
              ]
        }, 
        "contributors": null, 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "place": null, 
        "retweet_count": 4, 
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 20:24:49 +0000 2011", 
        "user": {
              "notifications": null, 
              "profile_use_background_image": true, 
              "statuses_count": 31, 
              "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
              "followers_count": 3066, 
              "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
              "listed_count": 6, 
              "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1301071706/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
              "description": "", 
              "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
              "default_profile": true, 
              "verified": false, 
              "time_zone": null, 
              "profile_text_color": "333333", 
              "is_translator": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
              "location": "", 
              "id_str": "271572434", 
              "default_profile_image": false, 
              "profile_background_tile": false, 
              "lang": "en", 
              "friends_count": 21, 
              "protected": false, 
              "favourites_count": 0, 
              "created_at": "Thu Mar 24 19:45:44 +0000 2011", 
              "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
              "name": "PostGradProblems", 
              "show_all_inline_media": false, 
              "follow_request_sent": null, 
              "geo_enabled": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
              "url": null, 
              "id": 271572434, 
              "contributors_enabled": false, 
              "following": null, 
              "utc_offset": null
        }, 
        "id": 54640519019642880, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "geo": null
  }, 
  "user": {
        "notifications": null, 
        "profile_use_background_image": true, 
        "statuses_count": 351, 
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
        "followers_count": 48, 
        "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/455128973/gCsVUnofNqqyd6tdOGevROvko1_500_normal.jpg", 
        "listed_count": 0, 
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1300479984/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "description": "watcha doin in my waters?", 
        "screen_name": "OldGREG85", 
        "default_profile": true, 
        "verified": false, 
        "time_zone": "Hawaii", 
        "profile_text_color": "333333", 
        "is_translator": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
        "location": "Texas", 
        "id_str": "80177619", 
        "default_profile_image": false, 
        "profile_background_tile": false, 
        "lang": "en", 
        "friends_count": 81, 
        "protected": false, 
        "favourites_count": 0, 
        "created_at": "Tue Oct 06 01:13:17 +0000 2009", 
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
        "name": "GG", 
        "show_all_inline_media": false, 
        "follow_request_sent": null, 
        "geo_enabled": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
        "url": null, 
        "id": 80177619, 
        "contributors_enabled": false, 
        "following": null, 
        "utc_offset": -36000
  }, 
  "id": 54691802283900930, 
  "coordinates": null, 
  "geo": null
} {{
  "text": "RT @PostGradProblem: In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during ...", 
  "truncated": true, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
  "favorited": false, 
  "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>", 
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
  "id_str": "54691802283900928", 
  "entities": {
        "user_mentions": [
              {
                    "indices": [
                          3, 
                          19
                    ], 
                    "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
                    "id_str": "271572434", 
                    "name": "PostGradProblems", 
                    "id": 271572434
              }
        ], 
        "urls": [ ], 
        "hashtags": [ ]
  }, 
  "contributors": null, 
  "retweeted": false, 
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
  "place": null, 
  "retweet_count": 4, 
  "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 23:48:36 +0000 2011", 
  "retweeted_status": {
        "text": "In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during company time. #PGP", 
        "truncated": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null, 
        "favorited": false, 
        "source": "<a href=\"http://www.hootsuite.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">HootSuite</a>", 
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, 
        "id_str": "54640519019642881", 
        "entities": {
              "user_mentions": [ ], 
              "urls": [ ], 
              "hashtags": [
                    {
                          "text": "PGP", 
                          "indices": [
                                130, 
                                134
                          ]
                    }
              ]
        }, 
        "contributors": null, 
        "retweeted": false, 
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
        "place": null, 
        "retweet_count": 4, 
        "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 20:24:49 +0000 2011", 
        "user": {
              "notifications": null, 
              "profile_use_background_image": true, 
              "statuses_count": 31, 
              "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
              "followers_count": 3066, 
              "profile_image_url": "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1285770264/PGP_normal.jpg", 
              "listed_count": 6, 
              "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1301071706/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
              "description": "", 
              "screen_name": "PostGradProblem", 
              "default_profile": true, 
              "verified": false, 
              "time_zone": null, 
              "profile_text_color": "333333", 
              "is_translator": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
              "location": "", 
              "id_str": "271572434", 
              "default_profile_image": false, 
              "profile_background_tile": false, 
              "lang": "en", 
              "friends_count": 21, 
              "protected": false, 
              "favourites_count": 0, 
              "created_at": "Thu Mar 24 19:45:44 +0000 2011", 
              "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
              "name": "PostGradProblems", 
              "show_all_inline_media": false, 
              "follow_request_sent": null, 
              "geo_enabled": false, 
              "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
              "url": null, 
              "id": 271572434, 
              "contributors_enabled": false, 
              "following": null, 
              "utc_offset": null
        }, 
        "id": 54640519019642880, 
        "coordinates": null, 
        "geo": null
  }, 
  "user": {
        "notifications": null, 
        "profile_use_background_image": true, 
        "statuses_count": 351, 
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED", 
        "followers_count": 48, 
        "profile_image_url": "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/455128973/gCsVUnofNqqyd6tdOGevROvko1_500_normal.jpg", 
        "listed_count": 0, 
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://a3.twimg.com/a/1300479984/images/themes/theme1/bg.png", 
        "description": "watcha doin in my waters?", 
        "screen_name": "OldGREG85", 
        "default_profile": true, 
        "verified": false, 
        "time_zone": "Hawaii", 
        "profile_text_color": "333333", 
        "is_translator": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6", 
        "location": "Texas", 
        "id_str": "80177619", 
        "default_profile_image": false, 
        "profile_background_tile": false, 
        "lang": "en", 
        "friends_count": 81, 
        "protected": false, 
        "favourites_count": 0, 
        "created_at": "Tue Oct 06 01:13:17 +0000 2009", 
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4", 
        "name": "GG", 
        "show_all_inline_media": false, 
        "follow_request_sent": null, 
        "geo_enabled": false, 
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED", 
        "url": null, 
        "id": 80177619, 
        "contributors_enabled": false, 
        "following": null, 
        "utc_offset": -36000
  }, 
  "id": 54691802283900930, 
  "coordinates": null, 
  "geo": null
}{"Another JSON response}{"Another JSON response"}
```

As you see, the tweets are sequently dumped into the json file and creating a **Multiple JSON root elements error**, which makes the file invalid.

**What I need:**

I need to separate every object while the API is streaming the tweets as I will place this file in Bigquery afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the file appending logic to:

```
with open('fetched_tweets.json','a') as tf:
    json.dump(data, tf)
    tf.write("\n")
```

Then when you read the file:

```
with open('fetched_tweets.json', 'r') as tf:
    for line in tf:
        data = json.loads(line)
        # save the `data` dictionary to BigQuery
```

Having the logic above will ensure each json object is on a separate line, thus separated by "\n".

Comment: I guess it works! You are amazing, thank you very much!